# PHPExcel create a new file

Tags: php, ajax, phpexcel

I am trying to create a new Excel file by using PHPExcel library with this code :

```
   include ('/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
   include ('/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');

   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()
   ->setCreator("admin")
   ->setLastModifiedBy("admin")
   ->setTitle("Test")
   ->setSubject("template file")
   ->setDescription("template file")
   ->setKeywords("Prout");
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
   $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
   $objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__).'/file/test.xlsx');
```

The file is created, but when i try to open it my excel 2010 tells me there is unreadable content inside the file and i can't open it.

I tried a different way on a different forum but i am always arriving to the same result. I do this manipulation by using Ajax with jquery. Can this be the cause of this error?

Comment: try with set header as well , it should solved your issue.

Comment: You're saving this file on the web server, so where does Ajax come into the picture?

Comment: The code that i show you is call by ajax with the help of jquery and i already try to put some header put it's for force the dowload no? And it's don't work with ajax. I will find how to resolve this problem after i resolve this one. Peraphs i can just don't pass by Ajax but i don't want that the user leave the page when he try to dowload the file

Comment: First point..... you're saving the file on the webserver, not sending it to the browser (there's examples with the PHPExcel distribution showing how to do that by sending appropriate __headers__ and saving to `php://output`)

Comment: Second point.... Ajax has no idea what to do with the binary stream of data that is an Excel file, so you need to handle that in you js code... or (more appropriately) use a link to the file creation script instead of using an Ajax request

Comment: Thank you Mark Baker i will try that and i come back tomorrow with the result.

Comment: I do like you say i change the line 
  `$objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__).'/file/test.xlsx');`
by this 3 lines :
   `header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"');
   $objWriter->save('php://output');`
And i pass by a normal link (i had some problem with header but i resolve them) and now when i click on the link i go to the page and the file is dowload but i still have the same  problem : I can't read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find how to resolve my problem ... but only half of it. Because it's work with this code :

```
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getProperties()
   ->setCreator("Temporaris")
   ->setLastModifiedBy("Temporaris")
   ->setTitle("Template Relevé des heures intérimaires")
   ->setSubject("Template excel")
   ->setDescription("Template excel permettant la création d'un ou plusieurs relevés d'heures")
   ->setKeywords("Template excel");
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', "12");

   $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="excel.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $writer->save('php://output');
```

But it's Excel5 not Excel2007 and when i remplace Excel5 by Excel2007 i have the same error message.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75530/discussion-on-answer-by-kvasir-phpexcel-creat-a-new-file).

Comment: Well I've examined the xlsx file: the zip index is intact, but the individual files fail on a crc check, so it's as though ZipArchive has somehow corrupted the individual files (or at least their crc32 value) when writing.... it's not something I can explain

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this ?

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
```